# What's the rush to pay my loans?

Tags: animal-crossing-pocket-camp

I recently got the interior of my trailer expanded. Now, I have a loan to pay off.

What's the rush to pay it off? I didn't see a timer anywhere, and I didn't see an interest rate in the loan app.

Do I even have to pay my loans?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like the loans in the console Animal Crossing games, there is neither a time limit nor interest on these loans. They do lock you out of further expansions to your camper until you repay them, but you can still buy paint jobs while your loan remains unpaid.

Comment: Basically, the AC loans is that you are paying for your next upgrade.

Comment: I've always found it to be psychological; it feels good to pay off the loan/mortage.